# Configuring traefik for basic http so that dashboard uses port 80 -- get page 404 not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cloudflare, traefik

My VPS is a ubuntu 22.04 LTS headless

I am doing this at `/home/ubuntu` so I have a `ubuntu` user that's a sudoer.

Already installed docker and running Docker `version 20.10.15, build fd82621`

My purpose is to **install and run traefik successfully with just plain http first**. It's to build towards my ultimate goal of running multiple apps each using a subdomain under `somedemowebsite.com` on the same VPS

### My Traefik Configuration

These are my steps at `/home/ubuntu`

```
mkdir traefik
cd traefik
mkdir data 
cd data
touch acme.json
chmod 600 acme.json
touch traefik.yml
```

This is my `/home/ubuntu/traefik/docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services: 
  traefik: 
    image: traefik:v2.6 
    container_name: traefik 
    restart: unless-stopped 
    security_opt: 
      - no-new-privileges:true 
    networks: 
      - proxy 
    ports: 
      - 80:80 
      - 443:443 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes: 
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro 
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro 
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/acme.json:/acme.json 
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro 
    labels: 
      - "traefik.enable=true" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(traefik.mydomaincom)" 
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=USER:BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"

networks: 
  proxy: 
    external: true
```

This is my `/home/ubuntu/traefik/data/traefik.yml`

```yaml
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
  insecure: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
log:
  filePath: "/var/log/traefik.log"
  format: json
  level: DEBUG
```

### DNS settings

I am using CloudFlare for my DNS

My CF configurations for `somedemowebsite.com` is

- SSL/TLS encryption mode is Off (not secure)
- SSL/TLS Recommender Yes
- Always Use HTTPS No

### Commands

At `/home/ubuntu/traefik` I did

```
docker network create proxy
docker compose up --force-recreate
```

I get a

```
[+] Running 1/0
⠿ Container traefik Created 0.1s
Attaching to traefik
traefik | time="2022-05-13T14:31:12Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: /traefik.yml"
```

### What I saw

I get a page 404 not found error when I went to `http://traefik.somedemowebsite.com`

### What i expected

to get prompted for basic auth for username and password

### Update

I can reach the dashboard when I use port 8080. but not port 80.

#### how to tell which reason cause this 404

I found this https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/faq/#404-not-found

there are 4 reasons. How do I debug in a way I can know which reason caused my 404?

I cite

> 1. A request reaching an EntryPoint that has no Routers
> 2. An HTTP request reaching an EntryPoint that has no HTTP Router
> 3. An HTTPS request reaching an EntryPoint that has no HTTPS Router
> 4. A request reaching an EntryPoint that has HTTP/HTTPS Routers that cannot be matched

I assume it's not 3 since I am explicitly only using http.

How do I tell whether it's 1, 2, or 4?

Comment: o'n your remote VPS, just `curl http://127.0.0.1:80` see what happened. @Kim Stacks the traefik management port was not 80 or 443, this is the service port. the older version of traffic using another port to see the management of traffic.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:80` i get 404 page not found

Comment: I can get to the traefik dashboard when i turn on api.insecure and add port 8080 to docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I have solved it.

The main culprit is that the domain is not wrapped in ticks. Also for the basic auth to work i need to assign the middleware to the router.

Comments are where the changes made things work. So for `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.6
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - /home/ubuntu/traefik/data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      # notice the ticks
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain`)"
      # added the middleware
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=USER:BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```